# Questions related to mantis:

Tags: installation, database, mantis

We are interested in installing Mantis but we have some doubts Please clarify as early as possible if you can so that we can go for further process.

1) We have one team at USA (Client’s place) and one is at India. In which server we should install the Mantis. If we are installing at USA will it run slow in India?

2) What about technical Support. You may take technical support with payment. But how much support will be given free (As we have to discuss this with client).

3) As we have seen details in your website, you have given it supports oracle and sql database. But we wanted to know till which lowest version of oracle and sql it supports. Please send us minimum requirement.

4) What is the capacity of the database to store defects? Backup facility is available? If yes please tell us how should we take. Because we have big team and 5-6 applications so it should not give further problems.

5) Database support: Do you provide database support or database while installation? While installing all the prerequisite application will get installed or we need any application separately.

6)How many users can access at a time? Will it work slowly if more users are working at a time?

Thanks
Komal

Comment: This looks like a request for a quote, not a technical question.

Answer (score 1):

1) assuming you can get a similar Internet link, place it where you have more users

2) assuming you have a VPN and LDAP running, you aren't likely to need heavy technical support unless you want to customize it, but anyway, Mantis provides support information on [it's web](http://www.mantisbt.org/support.php)

3) do you have a good reason why you don't want to use MySQL? Sure, you seem to have Oracle and MSSQL expertise in-house, but it's not like you would have to develop on MySQL: it's just basic infrastructure, one not very expensive to maintain.

4) It is unlikely you'll run into capacity problems unless your team really is huge. The database will store as many defects as needed. Backup: `mysqldump --user username --password > dbdump.sql`

5) you generally install the RDBMS and Apache separately and then deploy the Mantis application on top of those, dedicating an empty database to the application

6) slowdown is inevitable with a growing number of users, but that's beside the point: what's important is what kind of hardware you have and how many users. There have been a couple of discussions about Mantis performance (e.g. [this one](http://www.mantisbt.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=10270) and [this one](http://www.mantisbt.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=147)) but they are really quite old and are a bit on the extreme side (100k users).